# Bootstrap 3 collapsed menu on-click close issue

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="statics" class="main-bar">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

and use this to toggle responsive menu on element click:

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle') {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

But it does not work, unless I put some text between the 'a' tags, like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="statics" class="main-bar">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        **something**
    </a>
</li>
```

Hope to be clear...

Some help?

**UPDATE:**
The second option works only if i click on the text, but if I click on the glyphicon it does not...

Comment: What happens if you add a '&nbsp' inside the anchor tag?

Comment: @Mothermole1 Nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the span to the condition:

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
   if( ($(e.target).is('a') || $(e.target).is('span')) && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
      $(this).collapse('hide');
   }
});
```